# Apache & Tomcat Load balancing via Mod_jk issue

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, load-balancing, mod-jk, load-balance

I hope this finds you all in the best of your health and spirits. 
I have an issue with a new setup where I currently have 1 APACHE 2.2.15 & Tomcat 6.0.14 on RHEL. Mod_JK version 1.2.30. 
Ill add the second Tomcat when this starts working.

So when I try to point my browser to apache-host: port i get IT WORKS , but if point browser to host: port //examples/jsp/ 
i get a 404....apache isnt forwarding requests to Tomcat 
Tomcat works fine , i can browse to the JSP examples page and run stuff. 
I just cannot do it through the apache. 
Any help is very much appreciated...please help!!!!!

Here are my configs.... 
no virtual hosts configured...

```
HTTPD.CONF 
Include conf/jk/mod_jk.conf 
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so 

MOD_JK.CONF 
JkWorkersFile conf/jk/workers.properties 
JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm 
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log 
JkLogLevel info 
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] " 

WORKERS.PROPERTIES 
worker.list=loadbalancer,status 

# Node #1 properties 
worker.worker1.type=ajp13 
worker.worker1.host=localhost 
worker.worker1.port=8009 
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1 

# Node #2 properties(will be configured later when apache and node 1 start working) 
worker.worker2.type=ajp13 
worker.worker2.host=localhost 
worker.worker2.port=001 
worker.worker2.lbfactor=1 

# Load-balancing behaviour 
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb 
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2 

# Status worker for managing load balancer 
worker.status.type=status 

#JkMount /* loadbalancer 
JkMount /examples/jsp lb 
JkMount /examples/jsp/* lb 


tomcat server.xml has this 
<Service name="Catalina"> 
... 
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 --> 
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" /> 
... 
</Service>
```

Comment: where did you put `JkMount` config? workers.properties? it should be putted in Apache config file (or a file under `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directory).

Answer (score 1):

> WORKERS.PROPERTIES
>
> ```
> # Load-balancing behaviour 
> worker.loadbalancer.type=lb 
> worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2 
>
> #JkMount /* loadbalancer 
> JkMount /examples/jsp lb 
> JkMount /examples/jsp/* lb
> ```

This is wrong. Move the `JkMount` directive to the `mod_jk.conf`, something like this:

```
JkWorkersFile conf/jk/workers.properties 
JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm 
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log 
JkLogLevel info 
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] " 

JkMount /examples/jsp loadbalancer
JkMount /examples/jsp/* loadbalancer
```

Notice that the Tomcat worker should be `loadbalancer` as you defined in the `workers.properties`, instead of `lb`.

Comment: Got it working...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed both...now i just get a blank page....it does complain about second worker in mod_jk logs about host is down but i guess thats OK since i dont have worker 2 configured. It should route requests to worker 1 right?

i get this in access logs when i try host: port/examples/jsp

```
172.31.118.231 - - [22/Feb/2013:09:27:09 -0600] "GET /examples/jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.31.118.231 - - [22/Feb/2013:09:27:21 -0600] "GET /examples/jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.31.118.231 - - [22/Feb/2013:09:27:21 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
172.31.118.231 - - [22/Feb/2013:09:28:06 -0600] "GET /examples/jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.31.118.231 - - [22/Feb/2013:09:28:07 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

in error logs

```
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:00 2013] [error] [client 172.31.118.231] File does not exist: /opt/fas/loader/tomproj/apache2.2.15/htdocs/examples
```

in mod_jklogs

```
[Fri Feb 22 09:25:27 2013] [5773:47624974852416] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3189): mod_jk/1.2.30 initialized
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (622): connect to 127.0.0.1:1 failed (errno=111)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (959): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:1) (errno=111)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1585): (worker2) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2540): (worker2) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (622): connect to 127.0.0.1:1 failed (errno=111)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (959): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:1) (errno=111)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1585): (worker2) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2540): (worker2) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2559): (worker2) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Fri Feb 22 09:26:45 2013] [5777:1119607104] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1388): service failed, worker worker2 is in error state
```

its the

Comment: OK got it working.....after those 2 changes , i found out tomcat ajp port's configuration has an issue...i had this....<Service name="Catalina">
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
</Service>
.............................i removed <Service name="Catalina"> and removed /service....and only used <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />...tomcat worked fine...no errors.....apache work fine no errors....thank you Quanta & Liu Yuan!!!!